# What are the commands customarily shouted out to the crowd to leave?

Tags: phrase-request

What expressions (commands) do police customarily use when calling out over megaphones to a gathered crowd (a protest, demonstration or such) to walk away and end the protest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PLEASE DISPERSE.** (Not you, SF – that's just what might be said.)

It's worth showing NOAD's entry for disperse:

> **disperse** (*verb*) to go or cause to go in different directions or to different destinations : [ intrans. ] *the crowd dispersed* | [ trans. ] *the police used tear gas to disperse the protesters*.

There are probably other ways that this could be announced, but this was the one that immediately came to my mind.